# How to delete a vector pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I have created an array of vector using pointer and allocated its size using the `new` keyword. But when I tried to free the allocated memory, it gave me this error-

```
free(): invalid pointer  
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my code,

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

vector<int> *adjlist;

int main()
{
    adjlist = new vector<int>[10];    
    delete adjlist;    
    return 0;
}
```

The `new` keyword allocates in heap, so I tried to free heap memory using `delete`.
Because, unlike stack, the heap memory won't get cleared automatically.
When I used parentheses instead of square brackets, it didn't show me any error.

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

vector<int> *adjlist;

int main()
{
    adjlist = new vector<int>(10);    
    delete adjlist;    
    return 0;
}
```

So, why the first code is getting an error but not the second. And how do I free the heap memory?

Comment: The first one creates an ***array*** which must be destroyed with `delete[]`.

Comment: You allocated an array of 10 vector<int>s, not a vector of 10 ints

Comment: frankly, you should probably pick a better source for learning. A `vector<int>[10];` is an abdomination that maybe has some rare use-cases, but I have never seen one. I know that there are certain "tutorial" sites that promote such weird constructs, don't follow them

Comment: See also: [c++ - Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and  [c++ - Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Aside: You should not use new. `std::vector<int> adjlist(10);` gives you a vector of 10 ints

Comment: Or if you really want 10 `std::vector<int>`s, `std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> adjlist;` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>> adjlist(10);`

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik. It solved my issue.